# rcov outside rails

Tags: ruby, rspec, rcov

This may seem obvious but I don't find a way to run Rcov or coverMe outside a Rails project. 
I would like to use it with Rspec 2.5
I am using Ruby 1.9.2 so I guess this may be the problem.

I also would like not to use rake tasks but a command on the command line. I have tried several things and the best result I got is Rcov report for :

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rcov-0.9.9/lib/rcov/code_coverage_analyzer.rb

and

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rcov-0.9.9/lib/rcov/code_coverage_analyzer.rb

No idea why

Comment: Did you mean to repeat `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rcov-0.9.9/lib/rcov/code_coverage_analyzer.rb`?

Comment: I meant, the coverage/ directory only have data about these two files

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics.html for some alternatives to RCov if using Ruby 1.9 is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleCov, it runs awesome outside the Rails box.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/simplecov/0.5.4/frames

Answer (score 1):

The latest available version of `rcov` (0.9.8) still doesn't have good support for 1.9.2. You can try to run it on your project by doing:

```
 rcov spec/*.rb
```

But you'll most likely get something like:

```
 ** WARNING: Ruby 1.9 Support is experimental at best. Don't expect correct results! **
```

And then some errors after that.